# Dropdown event stops firing after specific selection

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have 2 asp dropdown controls and an asp grid control in an Updatepanel. Update Panel is set properties as `UpdateMode="Conditional"` `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`.

On change event of both dropdown I am calling a method which fetches data from SQL Table and binds to grid control. This works fine till data is less. Whenever I select a value from dropdown for which data is around 900+ records, it binds data to grid without any error. But doesn't trigger any other dropdown change event.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldept" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddldept_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="True"/>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYr" runat="server"OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlYr_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="True"/>

    <asp:DataList ID="gvData" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="gvData_ItemDataBound">


</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddldept" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What could be the reason of event stops triggering?

**EDIT 1:**

Found error in console:

> POST http://devserver:1111/mysite/SitePages/Main.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> ScriptResource.axd?d=FcwEEmnie6xhah_BvAg_MQP-cTp24dyFdRx9c2UxylFp5s8-W18rfLHBOC-uoS-F5J3jgyRFMZWkZS…:4803

Comment: is there any issue visible in Browser Console ?

Comment: I am putting debugger as well. but its not hitting the method

Comment: @SunilKumar. I found the error message in console. Updated main question.

Comment: Internal server Error due to your C# Code. Can you please put your C# code here

Comment: thanks for inputs.. I am able to resolve it. Since data was huge it was not able to refurbish the request.. so gave 500 internal server error.

Comment: you can refer this link for optimize your results:   
http://madskristensen.net/post/optimize-webresourceaxd-and-scriptresourceaxd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Just had to add following entry to web.config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="3001" />
</appSettings>
```

Started working